# Test if an array is empty or contains a certain object with

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I want to test if an array is empty or contains objects of a certain structure. In pseudo code it could be something like this:

```
expect([])
  .toHaveLength(0)
  .or
  .arrayContaining(
    expect.toMatchObject(
     { foo: expect.any(String) }
    )
  ) => true

expect([{foo: 'bar'}])
  .toHaveLength(0)
  .or
  .arrayContaining(
    expect.toMatchObject(
     { foo: expect.any(String) }
    )
  ) => true

expect([1])
  .toHaveLength(0)
  .or
  .arrayContaining(
    expect.toMatchObject(
      { foo: expect.any(String) }
    )
  ) => false
```

Maybe I'm getting it wrong on the how things work in Jest, but to me my problem looks like an or-question.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to encapsulate a logical or in your test suite would be to just exclude the particular case inside of the test itself. For example:

```
it('has an array of objects', () => {
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    expect(arr).toBe(expect.arrayContaining(expect.toMatchObject({ foo: expect.any(String) })));
  }
});
```

However, I think a more unit test-friendly approach would be to separate your concerns. One test for when there is an empty array, and one test for when the `foo` property is set to `'bar'`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I also found this article that, in combination with what you wrote, was very helpful https://medium.com/@andrei.pfeiffer/jest-matching-objects-in-array-50fe2f4d6b98

Comment: Yes, I think a custom matcher would be a great solution if you were finding yourself testing this case more often. Still, I wonder if you're writing one test case where you should be writing two